# Can ggplot change the direction of axis.ticks from downward to upward?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Something I want to realize is like the following:

[image: Sample]

You see the direction of the axis.ticks is upward.

So can ggplot make the direction of axis.ticks  upward?

For now I can realize this

[image: the plot I have created now]

You can see the axis.ticks.length have been set to zero with the command of [Axis Attributes · hadley/ggplot2 Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Axis-Attributes)
But this is not what I want and there seems little description of it online.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this achieves your goal:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, drat))
gg <- gg + geom_point(size=3)
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=17, vjust=-0.25, color="black"))
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=17, hjust=1, color="black"))
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks=element_line(color="black", size=0.5))
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.25, "cm"))
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks.margin=unit(0.5, "cm"))
gg
```

[image]

We're just modifying the tick size and "reversing" the length then making sure the tick labels are positioned properly after that.

Comment: Thanks! That's really works. In fact, I have also find the methods of reversing in [ggplot usergroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ggplot2/axis.ticks/ggplot2/OlGA8Gm9O7w/QqRM93lfoUwJ) But messed up but positioning elements properly after that.

Comment: Thanks! Physics is an old subject like hates to change with fashion. So I have to realize this, although Hadley have said that ticks inside a figure is terrible.[Hadley Wickham's answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ggplot2/axis.ticks/ggplot2/oXSbrhuzVmk/1qpEMllIYN4J)